# Detecting bugged touch after water spill

Tags: android

When android tablet screen gets spilled with water and you cleanup screen, a touch stays bugged on screen. Is there a way to detect it in code because onTouchEvent doesn't detect it and you have to restart the device because anywhere else you click, it just clicks on that bugged fixed touch. It looks like someone would constantly click on fixed spot but without an event, just holding in place

Comment: you may be needing to refer to fling gestures.. coz while wiping you wont be touching the screen but u'll be flinging on it..check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection?rq=1

Comment: I would smack the user first. It's like 'protecting' your PC application for a lot of characters when you fall asleep with your head on the keyboard. I would say 'Out of scope' of your app.

Comment: then don't spill water on it, that's how my USB port died on my phone. TWICE. Like, what the hell.

Comment: @NightCrawler The problem is that I have a tablet and it is possible that tablet gets spilled, in some cases. And when you clean it up, some touch events stay fixed on a place, and I don't know how to handle and remove those touch events, because after that user has to restart the device because no other touch event will work. With fling gestures it is the same problem. I cannot know if someone mad a fling gesture or water was spilled. I cannot just disable/enable screen on every fling gesture